# Change size of leftIcon in ListItem (material ui)

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a react project and I want to increase the height and width of leftIcon in ListItem of material ui. I am passing an image to leftIcon and I want to set the height of this image equal to the height of listItem. I tried giving className to img tag and then setting the height and width from css, but it didn't work.

here is my ListItem

```
<MuiThemeProvider>
                    <List style={{margin:0, height:58}}>
                        <ListItem leftIcon={ <img className="mediaThumbnail" src="./dev/js/images/paris.jpg"/>} style={{height:70,backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF"}} secondaryText={value.Episode_Name}>
                        </ListItem>
                    </List>
                </MuiThemeProvider>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an working example where I use the ListItem component with an `<img>` as the `leftIcon` prop. I also give that `<img>` a class and a custom style.

https://jsfiddle.net/tecnkym7/1/